# [ Flutter QRcode successive scans ]

Tags: flutter, qr-code, flutter-qrcode

I'm developing a Flutter application based on QRcode scan.

I'd want the user to be able to scan multiple QRCODES without exiting the scan screen so we can scan like ten of them in a row that would update a results list and when the user manually exit the screen and is back on previous screen would display this results list.

- How can i achieve this please ?
- Is there a Qr code reader package from pub.dev allowing this ?

Thanks for any help !

PS : I'm actually using "qr_flutter" lib here : https://pub.dev/packages/qr_flutter
because it seems to be the most popular but can change if needed.

EDIT :: Also checking this one :: qr_code_scanner 0.5.2 https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner
as popular as the first one and seems to allow continuous scan for QRcodes...

Answer (score 1):

if you want to try continiusly scan for the screen check this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_barcode_scanner

Comment: thanks but seems to only work with barcodes and not QRcodes no ?

Comment: ı used before Qr code. And package support the a lat of barcode types

Answer (score 0):

Well i finally used qr_code_scanner 0.5.2

> https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner

That works very well and allows to scan several QRcodes in a row and personnalize your "QRView" as you want.

That's, of course, more code than using the 1st lib which gives you it's own "QRview" and just return a single scan result per time.

So

> 1st lib > 1 result per time / easiest to use

> 2nd lib > customize as you want ^^